# NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: tabbed-events-title

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

This is my code:

```
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
import time
import pandas as pd
import pickle
import re
from fuzzywuzzy import process, fuzz
from prettytable import PrettyTable


executablePath = r'C:\Users\AV\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\geckodriver.exe'

options = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
options.add_argument("--headless")

driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path = executablePath, options=options)
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("https://www.powerplay.com/sportsbook/SOCCER/")

upcomingMatches = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("tabbed-events-title")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", upcomingMatches)
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", upcomingMatches)

review = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("events-app__event__players__team")
for post in review:
    print(post.text)
review2 = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("events-app__event__players__v js-players-v")
for post in review2:
    print(post.text)
review3 = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("events-app__event__players__team events-app__event__players__team--away")
for post in review3:
    print(post.text)
```

all the imported stuff are for later,
my problem is that I get an error saying "selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: tabbed-events-title" but the element is on my screen...
I need to press on the button "upcoming matches" and print the names of the groups from there.
My HTML source:

```
<h2 class="tabbed-events-title">Upcoming Matches</h2>
```

Comment: did you try adding wait after driver.get()?

Comment: If you are trying to find an element with class = 'tabbed-events-title' then your CSS selector should be `".tabbed-events-title"`. Take note of the leading dot (.)

Comment: It still does not work with the (.) before... but thanks for responding!

Answer (score 1):

See if this works:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//h2[text()='Upcoming Matches']").click()
```

Comment: also are you accepting the cookies that appear on the page before trying to access the element?

Comment: I am not getting any error, it just stays blank.

Comment: I just tried accepting the cookies and it didn't change anything.